# Prolog importing facts from a formatted text file

Tags: io, prolog

I have the following input in a text file input.txt

```
atom1,atom2,atom3
relation(atom1  ,[10,5,2])
relation(atom2  ,[3,10,2])
relation(atom3  ,[6,5,10])
```

First line includes the list of atoms used in relation predicates in the file and each remaining line represents a relation predicate in order of the first line list.relation(atom1, [x,y,z]) means atom1 has a relation value of 10 with first atom, 5 with the second and 2 with the third
I need to read this file and add represent relation values  for each atom seperately.For example , these are the relation values which will be added for atom1 :

```
assert(relation(atom1, atom1,10)).
assert(relation(atom1, atom2, 5)).
assert(relation(atom1, atom3, 2)).
```

I have read some prolog io tutorials and seen some recommendations on using DCG  but I'm a beginner prolog programmer and having trouble to choose the method for the solving problem. So I'm here to ask help from experienced prolog programmers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't stated what Prolog you're using, here is a snippet written in SWI-Prolog. I attempted to signal *non* ISO builtins by means of SWI-Prolog docs reference.

```
parse_input :-
    open('input.txt', read, S),
    parse_line(S, atoms(Atoms)),
    repeat,
    (  parse_line(S, a_struct(relation(A, L)))
    -> store(Atoms, A, L), fail
    ;  true ),
    close(S).

:- meta_predicate(parse_line(+, //)).

parse_line(S, Grammar) :-
    % see http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=read_line_to_codes/2
    read_line_to_codes(S, L),
    L \= end_of_file,
    phrase(Grammar, L).

% match any sequence
% note - clauses order is mandatory
star([]) --> [].
star([C|Cs]) --> [C], star(Cs).

% --- DCGs ---

% comma sep atoms
atoms(R) -->
    star(S),
    (   ",",
        {atom_codes(A, S), R = [A|As]},
        atoms(As)
    ;   {atom_codes(A, S), R = [A]}
    ).

% parse a struct X,
% but it's far easier to use a builtin :)
% see http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=atom_to_term/3
a_struct(X, Cs, []) :-
    atom_codes(A, Cs),
    atom_to_term(A, X, []).

% storage handler
:- dynamic(relation/3).

store(Atoms, A, L) :-
    nth1(I, L, W),
    nth1(I, Atoms, B),
    assertz(relation(A, B, W)).
```

with the sample input.txt, I get

```
?- parse_input.
true .

?- listing(relation).
:- dynamic relation/3.

relation(atom1, atom1, 10).
relation(atom1, atom2, 5).
relation(atom1, atom3, 2).
relation(atom2, atom1, 3).
relation(atom2, atom2, 10).
relation(atom2, atom3, 2).
relation(atom3, atom1, 6).
relation(atom3, atom2, 5).
relation(atom3, atom3, 10).
```

HTH

Comment: I am using swi-prolog. So , that suited great !! Thank you ever so much!

Comment: But using assertz instead of assert does that create any difference ?

Comment: no, assertz/1 it's the same of assert/1. Or better, it's the officially (ISO ) accepted name.